# jQuery Slide Effect is Jerky

Tags: jquery

So I'm trying to do a kind of "click this to get a new thing" with jQuery's slide function.

Basically my problem is that the slide animation is jumpy and it's caused by the border that I set in the .toggleO class. The obvious solution is to get rid of the border, but I would like to keep it, so I was wondering if there was some way to do that while having a smooth transition?

Here's the snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".toggleO").click(function() {
    $(".toggleO").slideUp(500);
    $(".toggledInfo").slideDown(500);
  });

  $(".toggleC").click(function() {
    $(".toggledInfo").slideUp(500);
    $(".toggleO").slideDown(500);
  });

});
```

```css
#container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 350px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 11px;
  line-height: 13px;
}

#container .toggleO {
  width: 490px;
  height: 340px;
  background-image: url("http://ultraimg.com/images/8de3786443f8af4db9e4a29b8b658c00.jpg");
  cursor: crosshair;
  border: 5px solid black;
}

#container .toggleC {
  width: 500px;
  margin-top: 25px;
  font-family: georgia, times new roman, serif;
  font-size: 8px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  cursor: crosshair;
}

#container .toggledInfo {
  display: none;
}

#container .inside {
  padding: 50px;
  width: 400px;
  height: 260px;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id='container'>
  <div class='toggleO'></div>

  <div class='toggledInfo'>
    <div class='inside'>
      here are links about my thing yep

      <div class='toggleC'>
        close
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's the link to my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hsin/o0LcoLg1/7/) since it's easier to see there.

Comment: what is jerky exactly do you mean? I couldn't see such problem.

Comment: @BhojendraNepal When it's transitioning between the image and the text, the white square the text is in jerks into the final position. It's after the image has already done the slideUp but the borders are still there and it just disappears, causing the box of text to kind of jump. I've changed the border colour to black so you can see it better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Required changes :

1. I changed a few lines in your css like height in #container.inside css as it is supposed to be 250px instead of 260px.
2. Another thing I changed was that I included a wrapper div on the 'toggleO' div to prevent effects of the border on the animation. Since now the animation will be applied to wrapper and not toggleO which contains border.
3. The third and most important change was including "overflow:hidden;" in #container css. This will remove the little jerk which remains after applying the above steps.

Here is a modified jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/o0LcoLg1/8/

And the code snippet :

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.js" integrity="sha256-laXWtGydpwqJ8JA+X9x2miwmaiKhn8tVmOVEigRNtP4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <style>
    #container {
      width: 500px;
      height: 350px;
      margin: 0px auto;
      font-family: arial;
      font-size: 11px;
      line-height: 13px;
      overflow: hidden; // for the little jerk
    }
    #container .toggleO {
      width: 490px;
      height: 340px;
      background-image: url("http://ultraimg.com/images/8de3786443f8af4db9e4a29b8b658c00.jpg");
      cursor: crosshair;
      border: 5px solid black;
    }
    #container .toggleC {
      width: 500px;
      margin-top: 25px;
      font-family: georgia, times new roman, serif;
      font-size: 8px;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      letter-spacing: 1px;
      cursor: crosshair;
    }
    #container .toggledInfo {
      display: none;
    }
    #container .inside {
      padding: 50px;
      width: 400px;
      height: 250px;
      background-color: #000;
      color: #fff;
    }
  </style>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

      $(".wrapper").click(function() {
        $(".wrapper").slideUp(500);
        $(".toggledInfo").slideDown(500);
      });

      $(".toggleC").click(function() {
        $(".toggledInfo").slideUp(500);
        $(".wrapper").slideDown(500);
      });

    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id='container'>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class='toggleO'></div>
    </div>
    <div class='toggledInfo'>
      <div class='inside'>
        here are links about my thing yep

        <div class='toggleC'>
          close
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Would you be able to explain how the overflow: hidden works to remove that jerk? Why doesn't adding the wrapper class do the trick?

Comment: Adding the wrapper div, did reduce the jump to a minimum but it was still there. Just a pixel or so, but still there. The idea was to restrict the container div to its defined size i.e. 500px X 350px, since the jump was due to the extra pixel overflowing this defined size. So, it was an intuition to hide the overflow of the container div to avoid the jump. Hope I was able to help. :) Cheers :)

Comment: I see. Thanks for your help!